# Associative array crash?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Associative arrays don't work for me in php.

So when I create an associative array in php and run it in firefox or chrome, it doesn't seems like to work. The code just got cut in half. I tested it on w3school and works there, but if I copy-paste it to an html file and run it, it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
echo "Peter is " . $age['Peter'] . " years old.";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect that can work like on this site: https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_array_assoc,
but it didn't.

Comment: Do you have a webserver ? And what do you mean by *it doesn't work* ?

Comment: check that your file extension is php and webserver installed!

Comment: you said in html file . you need to copy to .php file

Comment: Please read the PHP tag info: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Php is a programming language and is responsible on processing programming logic just like what you are trying to accomplish.

Having said that you need to install a webserver and php on your computer.

I think that's were you should start.

If you are using windows, you can easily enable IIS (webserver) and install PHP using Microsoft's Web Platform installer at https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx